# Why is Spawn() never being called?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, spawn

I have had some experience with node.js and express for quite some time, but I keep running into this bug in my code. In my service file, I am calling spawn() inside a resolved Promise in my code. Somehow my spawn code is never called (or if it is called, `ls.on('close')` or `ls.on('error')` never gets called), and I don't know why. I think I understand the asynchronous nature of `Spawn()`, but I guess I don't? ‍♂️ Here is the code below from my `finalSendFiles.service.js` file:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const finalSendFiles = async (uVal) => {

    try {
        //new code
        console.log("I'm here")
        const getfirst_username = get_username(uVal);
        getfirst_username.then(function (username_value) {
            const pyScript = "./pythonFile.py"
            //spawn python file - this command  never gets called
            const ls = spawn('python', [pyScript, "./json_files/file1.json", "./json_files/file2.json", `${username_value}`])
            ls.on("error", (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            });

            ls.on("close", (code) => {
                console.log("You're done with the file!");
                console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    finalSendFiles
}
```

I would appreciate any help on a way forward!

P.S. The two files that are needed to send are written to the system using `fs.writeFile()`, so those files need to be done before the spawn actually executes

---

Update (06/01/20): I have done some testing using mocha.js and found some interesting findings. First, when I run `npm test` on the code below, everything is successful.

```
test.js

describe('spawnFunc', function() {
  describe('#spawn()', function() {
    it('it should call the python script', function(done) {
      const pyScript = "./p1.py"
      const ls = spawn('python', [pyScript])

      ls.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data.toString());
      }).on("close", (code) => {
        console.log("You're done with the .csv file bro!");
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
        done()
      });
    });
  });

});
```

The ouput of the my code is:

```
> mocha

  spawnFunc
    #spawn()
You've made it to the python file!

You're done with the .csv file bro!
child process exited with code false
```

So somehow, my testing is working. However, when I do `const ls = spawn('python', ["./p1.py"])` in my regular code it never gets to the spawn. I have already tried `python-shell` and that is not working either. I seem to be running into this same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318802/node-js-child-process-spawn-is-unable-to-launch-python-process)

Again any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the promise gets resolved?

Comment: What happens when you use a step-through debugger?

Comment: Perhaps the promise that `get_username()` returns ends up rejecting.  You don't have a `.catch()` handler to detect and handle that.  Also, your `finalSendFiles()` function will return long before the `spawn()` operation is done in case that is also what is confusing you.

Comment: @Dai - how do I use that?

Comment: @jeff-ridgeway https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: @jfriend00 - I figured something like that was going on. Yeah I need `spawn()` to return first and then `finalSendFiles()`. Since it's asynchronous, could it be something is wrong with my `pythonFile.py` that's not working correctly? 

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple possibilities:

1. The promise that `get_username()` returns could end up rejecting. You don't have a `.catch()` handler to detect and handle that.
2. Also, your `finalSendFiles()` function will return long before the `spawn()` operation is done in case that is also what is confusing you.

> I figured something like that was going. Yeah I need `spawn()` to return first and then `finalSendFiles()`

Well, you can't prevent `finalSendFiles()` from returning before the `spawn()` is done (that's the nature of asynchronous logic in Javascript) unless you use `spawnSync()` which will block your entire process during the `spawnSync()` operation which is generally not something you ever want to do in a server.

If you want to retain the asynchronous version of `spawn()`, then you will need to return a promise from `finalSendFiles()` that is linked to the completion of your `spawn()` operation.  You can do that like this:

```
const finalSendFiles = (uVal) => {
    console.log("I'm here")
    return get_username(uVal).then(function (username_value) {
        const pyScript = "./pythonFile.py"
        //spawn python file - this command  never gets called
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const ls = spawn('python', [pyScript, "./json_files/file1.json", "./json_files/file2.json", `${username_value}`])
            ls.on("error", (err) => {
                console.log(err)
                reject(err);
            }).on("close", (code) => {
                console.log("You're done with the file!");
                console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
                resolve(code);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Note: your caller will have to use the promise that it returns to see both completion and errors like this:

```
finalSendfiles(...).then(code => {
    console.log(`Got return code ${code}`);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: So I used this code and the only thing that is printed out in my terminal is `"I'm Here"`. Nothing else is printed. The code never gets to `"You're done with the file!"` or the next log statement. I also did `finalSendFiles` in my controller script. Does this mean something is up with my python file I'm using? Maybe I'm not processing things correctly there?

Comment: @jeff-ridgeway - I can't know for sure without being able to run the code myself, but it seems to point to a problem either with `get_username()` rejecting or with your python program that apparently isn't causing an error or exiting.  If you put some logging in your python program, can you verify that it is being run?

Comment: I put some logging in my python program and it is not running at all. I think my python program is even being run. Maybe the hang up is with `get_username()`?

Comment: @jeff-ridgeway - Do you have a `.catch()` handler when you call `finalSendfiles()` like I show?  If not, you need one in order to see that error.

Comment: yep I have the `.catch()` handler when I call `finalSendfiles()`. I don't know if it helps but `get_username` is an async function

Comment: @jeff-ridgeway - I'm out of guesses without seeing a bunch more code so I could see the entire code flow start from the incoming request and going all the way to the spawn.

Comment: I have made an update to the code as I have done some testing with mocha.js. check out the update above

Comment: @jeff-ridgeway - You see the `ls.on("error", (err) => {...});` in my answer?  Add that to your code to see if there's an error that will help you learn something.